# need help on solving my ffmpeg command line

Tags: ffmpeg

i create a small bash script to encode 1080p video , the video will be added with watermark at bottom left and i need to add a black padding on top and bottom

i tried several way but still no luck , i tried -vf and yes it worked but cant use padding and watermark together , and suggest use filter_complex

if i use this code directly without bash script it work

```
time ffmpeg -hide_banner -i transformers.mp4 -i transformers.ass -loop 1 -i watermark.png -loop 1 -i logo.png -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -filter_complex "[0:0]scale=(iw*sar)*min(1920/(iw*sar)\,800/ih):ih*min(1920/(iw*sar)\,800/ih), pad=1920:800:(1920-iw*min(1920/iw\,800/ih))/2:(800-ih*min(1920/iw\,800/ih))/2;ass=transformers.ass[FID1];[FID1][2:v]overlay=10:${WATERMARKPOSITION}:repeatlast=0:enable='between(t,300,600)'[FID3];[3:v]fade=in:st=1200:d=1.6:alpha=1,fade=out:st=107998:d=1.6:alpha=1[FID6];[FID3][FID6]overlay=10:5:repeatlast=0:enable='between(t,1200,187922)'" -c:v libx264 -minrate 1800k -maxrate 1800k -bufsize 3600k -profile:v high -c:a aac -b:a 128k -profile:a aac_main -movflags faststart -strict -2 -f mp4 -y "transformers.mp4"
```

but when i include it with my bash script i got this error ,

```
[libx264 @ 0x2a063e0] height not divisible by 2 (300x39)
Output #0, mp4, to '/movie/Paddy/output/Transformers.Age.of.Extinction.2014.1080p.BluRay.H264.AAC-RARBG.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    comment         : Transformers.Age.of.Extinction.2014.1080p.BluRay.H264.AAC-RARBG
    encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
    title           : Transformers Age of Extinction 2014 1080p BluRay H264 AAC-RARBG - Visit us @ Juraganfilm.COM
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264), yuv420p, 1920x800 [SAR 1:1 DAR 12:5], q=-1--1, max. 2300 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbn, 23.98 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 libx264
    Stream #0:1: Video: h264, none, q=2-31, 128 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 0:0, 25 fps
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 libx264
    Stream #0:2(eng): Audio: aac, 0 channels, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-12-19 07:58:39
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 aac
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> scale (graph 0)
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> overlay:overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #2:0 (png) -> ass (graph 0)
  Stream #3:0 (png) -> fade (graph 0)
  pad (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
  overlay (graph 0) -> Stream #0:1 (libx264)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:2 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:1 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

and below is the script i have been working on

```
output="/movie/output"

FILESDIR=`find $PWD -type f -regex ".*\.\(mp4\|mkv\|avi\)" | sed 's@.*/@@' | sort -n`
for video in $FILESDIR
do

MOVIETITLE=${video%.*}
INFOVID=${MOVIETITLE//./ }
BITRATE="${HEIGHT}"
WIDTH=$(ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=width,height -of csv=s=x:p=0 ${video} 2>&1 | sed -e 's|\[.*||g' | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g' | sed -e 's|x.*||g')
HEIGHT=$(ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=width,height -of csv=s=x:p=0 ${video} | sed -e 's/.*x//')
WATERMARKPOSITION=$(expr $HEIGHT - 50)
VIDEOMAP=$(ffmpeg -i $video 2>&1 | grep "Stream #" | grep Video | sed -e "s|.*\#||g" | sed -e "s|: Video.*||g" | sed -e "s|(.*||g")
AUDIOMAP=$(ffmpeg -i $video 2>&1 | grep "Stream #" | grep Audio | sed -e "s|.*\#||g" | sed -e "s|: Audio.*||g" | sed -e "s|(.*||g")
MAXRATE=$(expr $BITRATE + 500)
BUFFSIZE=$(expr $MAXRATE \* 2)

time ffmpeg -hide_banner -i $video -i $MOVIETITLE.ass -loop 1 -i $WATERMARK -loop 1 -i $LOGO -map ${VIDEOMAP} -map ${AUDIOMAP} -filter_complex "[${VIDEOMAP}]scale=(iw*sar)*min(${WIDTH}/(iw*sar)\,${HEIGHT}/ih):ih*min(${WIDTH}/(iw*sar)\,${HEIGHT}/ih), pad=${WIDTH}:${HEIGHT}:(${WIDTH}-iw*min(${WIDTH}/iw\,${HEIGHT}/ih))/2:(${HEIGHT}-ih*min(${WIDTH}/iw\,${HEIGHT}/ih))/2;ass=$MOVIETITLE.ass[FID1];[FID1][2:v]overlay=10:${WATERMARKPOSITION}:repeatlast=0:enable='between(t,300,600)'[FID3];[3:v]fade=in:st=1200:d=1.6:alpha=1,fade=out:st=107998:d=1.6:alpha=1[FID6];[FID3][FID6]overlay=10:5:repeatlast=0:enable='between(t,1200,187922)'" -c:v libx264 -minrate ${BITRATE}k -maxrate ${MAXRATE}k -bufsize ${BUFFSIZE}k -profile:v high -c:a aac -b:a 128k -profile:a aac_main -movflags faststart -strict -2 -f mp4 -y "${output}/$MOVIETITLE.mp4"
done
```

has been working all day and still i cant make it to work.

can someone guide me which part is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

1) Remove the mapping. Unlabelled filter_complex output is automatically mapped, so `-map 0:0` will map the unprocessed video stream. Without any maps. one audio stream will be [picked up](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Automatic-stream-selection), and there's only one, among your inputs.

2) After your pad, there's a semi-colon, which makes it an unlabelled filter_complex output, that gets directly sent to the output

```
pad (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
```

And so, the ass filter doesn't have an input and it ends up using watermark.png. The overlay and other filters are applied to this stream. And its size is not divisible by 2.

```
overlay (graph 0) -> Stream #0:1 (libx264)
```

The semi-colon should be a comma.

3) The ass filter is directly reading the subtitles file. It does not need to be fed as a regular input.

`time ffmpeg -hide_banner -i transformers.mp4 -loop 1 -i watermark.png -loop 1 -i logo.png -filter_complex "[0:0]scale=(iw*sar)*min(1920/(iw*sar)\,800/ih):ih*min(1920/(iw*sar)\,800/ih), pad=1920:800:(1920-iw*min(1920/iw\,800/ih))/2:(800-ih*min(1920/iw\,800/ih))/2, ass=transformers.ass[FID1];[FID1][2:v]overlay=10:${WATERMARKPOSITION}:repeatlast=0:enable='between(t,300,600)'[FID3];[3:v]fade=in:st=1200:d=1.6:alpha=1,fade=out:st=107998:d=1.6:alpha=1[FID6];[FID3][FID6]overlay=10:5:repeatlast=0:enable='between(t,1200,187922)'" -c:v libx264 -minrate 1800k -maxrate 1800k -bufsize 3600k -profile:v high -c:a aac -b:a 128k -profile:a aac_main -movflags faststart -strict -2 -f mp4 -y "transformers.mp4"`

Also, your numbers for fade out and last overlay look wrong. `st=107998` repesents 107888 **seconds** i.e. 30 **hours**. Same goes for `between(t,1200,187922)`

Comment: nice dude! it work after i remove the video mapping and audio mapping , also the semicolon part , fiuhhh finally after all day i found the light! thanks a lot bro!

Comment: btw any other suggestion you can give me for better encoding ? or any fix for my ffmpeg code?

Answer (score 0):

As for your script:

#### Simplify your `ffprobe` commands

This will eliminate four instances of `sed`.

Change:

```
WIDTH=$(ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=width,height -of csv=s=x:p=0 ${video} 2>&1 | sed -e 's|\[.*||g' | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g' | sed -e 's|x.*||g')
HEIGHT=$(ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=width,height -of csv=s=x:p=0 ${video} | sed -e 's/.*x//')
```

To:

```
WIDTH=$(ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=width -of csv=p=0 ${video})
HEIGHT=$(ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=height -of csv=p=0 ${video})
```

#### Use `ffprobe` instead of `ffmpeg` to parse info

The stderr output from `ffmpeg` is not meant to be machine parsed. Use `ffprobe` instead. That's what it is for.

So instead of:

```
VIDEOMAP=$(ffmpeg -i $video 2>&1 | grep "Stream #" | grep Video | sed -e "s|.*\#||g" | sed -e "s|: Video.*||g" | sed -e "s|(.*||g")
```

This is fragile and will return multiple results if an input has more than one video stream.

Instead you can do:

```
VIDEOMAP=$(ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=index -of csv=p=0 $video)
```

For audio just change the [stream specifier](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-specifiers-1) in [`-select_streams`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html#Main-options) (change `v` to `a`).

However, this particular example is a moot point because...

#### Just use stream specifiers

No need for `VIDEOMAP` and `AUDIOMAP`.

Instead of:

```
VIDEOMAP=$(ffmpeg -i $video 2>&1 | grep "Stream #" | grep Video | sed -e "s|.*\#||g" | sed -e "s|: Video.*||g" | sed -e "s|(.*||g")
AUDIOMAP=$(ffmpeg -i $video 2>&1 | grep "Stream #" | grep Audio | sed -e "s|.*\#||g" | sed -e "s|: Audio.*||g" | sed -e "s|(.*||g")
```

In your `-filter_complex` use:

- `0:v:0` to refer to the first video stream
- `0:a:0` to refer to the first audio stream

#### `ffmpeg`

No need for cargo cult usage of `-strict -2`. That used to be required when the FFmpeg AAC encoder was considered experimental. It hasn't been experimental for years, but users keep adding it from old, rotten examples and copy and paste rote usage.

Don't use `-profile:v high`. Unless you need to restrict to a lesser profile (Main or Baseline) for compatibility with older or limited devices/players, then just let the encoder choose the profile.

You don't need `-f mp4` unless your output file name is ambiguous (such as missing the extension).

#### Use shellcheck.net to check your script

[shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) will help you clean up your script and prevent issues: it has many suggestions regarding your script.